# how to get deviceValue in the other function?

Tags: angular

status: string = "";

```
setStatus(deviceValue) {
this.status = deviceValue.valueOf();
return this.status;
}

update(value: string, index: number, item: number) {

this.setStatus(???)    

alert(this.status);
if (this.status == '1') {something}
else if (this.status == '2') {something}
}
```

in the case, how can I get the deviceValue and put in update() ?

Comment: Can you please add more details about deviceValue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rewritten this to explain what may be missing.

```
public status: TYPE; // you define `status` and its type

// this sets `status` to deviceValue.valueOf() when selection is made
setStatus(deviceValue: type) {
    this.status = deviceValue.valueOf();
}

// use your global status
update(value: string, index: number, item: number) {
    if (this.status == '1') {
        something
    } else if (this.status == '2') {
        something
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<select id="portOrigin" (change)="setStatus($event.target.value)">
  ...
</select>
```

Comment: setStatus() can get a drop down box option values (1/2)

an input box will run update()

each time user click the input box , setStatus will tigger and return drop down box values(1/2)

Comment: I've updated the question. If you need more help could you create a StackBlitz?